# 8 Monitors. Need batch file that opens specific webpage on each monitor automatically

Tags: javascript, batch-file, powershell, multiple-monitors

I have  monitors and I need 8 specific websites to automatically come up maximized on each one using a batch file or a tool. Using windows server 2008 r2 and IE11. Any ideas? I've looked and found some examples but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

EDIT

Current batch looks like this

```
start iexplore http://google.com
start iexplore http://google.com
start iexplore http://google.com
start iexplore http://google.com
start iexplore http://google.com
```

but I need them to autop open on diff monitors full screened

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this with javascript I think.

Type this into the URL field:

```
javascript:resizeTo(1980,1080);moveTo(0,0)

javascript:resizeTo(1980,1080);moveTo(1981,0)

etc...
```

This will not work in Chrome. It will work in Internet Explorer, however.

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)

Comment: so how exactly would that work?
    start iexplore http://google.com javascript:resizeTo(1980,1080);moveTo(0,0);